# How to remove a ".php" extension and add "/" at the end of the URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to know how I can rewrite the following URL:

```
mydomain.com/service-demo.php
```

so that it can be accessed using one of:

```
mydomain.com/service-demo/
mydomain.com/service-demo
mydomain.com/service-demo.php
```

but always show this:

```
mydomain.com/service-demo/
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

create a new file (.htaccess ) in root folder
and write this codes

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```